# Nonexistent function 'instance' in base 'Nil' in Godot for instancing the player

Tags: null, save, instance, godot, gdscript

I am currently working on my game's save and load states, and I created a global script to use it. In the script, I preload the player scene and then later in the load_game() function I instance it. And the instance doesn't seem to work.

I get the error "Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'instance' on base 'Nil'". I have tried  to use load instead of preload (didn't work). This is my first time making save and load states so I am bit puzzled about how to access the player scene in a global script.

Here is the code:

```
onready var playerCharacter = preload("res://Player/Player.tscn").new()
```

This line here is getting the error:

```
var player = playerCharacter.instance()
```

Thanks in advance for any help. I'd appreciate any godot docs that can help me understand this and also help me in saving and loading my game. Currently I am using .dat files I learnt from GameEndeavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression:

```
preload("res://Player/Player.tscn")
```

If the path is correct, will give you an `PackedScene` object.

---

This expression:

```
preload("res://Player/Player.tscn").new()
```

I'm surprised it is not giving you an error. The `new` method is static, and should not be called on an object. From the error you got, I'm gessing this is returning `null`.

---

You can use `preload`, but with a `const` like this:

```
const playerCharacter = preload("res://Player/Player.tscn")
```

This is possible because `preload` keyword gives you constant expression and it is resolved while parsing. And it should also make Godot complain if you add something that is not a constant expression such as `.new()`.

*If you use `load` then you can't use `const`, however it should also work. Using `load` will load the `PackedScene` when Godot executes the line. Using `preload` Godot will load the `PackedScene` when Godot loads the script. You might also be interested in the `ResourceLoader` class.*

---

Once you have your `PackedScene` object, you should be able to call `instance` on it:

```
var player = playerCharacter.instance()
```

*For future reference: in Godot 4 it is `instantiate`.*

---

To satisfy curiosity and clear confusion… You can create a `PackedScene` with `new` like this:

```
var packed_scene := PackedScene.new()
```

But only do that if you wanted to create an scene from code. Which you can save to a file using the `ResourceSaver` class. For example:

```
var packed_scene := PackedScene.new()
packed_scene.pack(node)
ResourceSaver.save("res://new_scene.tscn", packed_scene)
```

Which might be useful, for example, when running code from the editor (perhaps as part of a plugin), but that is not what you are doing here.

Comment: This was exactly what was going wrong, now it is working fine. Thank you so much for the explanation for the PackedScene and others.

Comment: Also, Is there any documentation I can use to understand more about PackedScene

Comment: @DinoNyte There is the official documentation: [PackedScene](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_packedscene.html). You might also look at the source code [packed_scene.cpp](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.x/scene/resources/packed_scene.cpp). However, for practical use see [godot-demo-projects](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-demo-projects). With that said, I remind you that you can always post a new question. And if you can't or rather not ask here, check [Godot's Community](https://godotengine.org/community).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var player = playerCharacter.instantiate()
```